# ClassnotFoundException while running a java class through crontab using unix?

Tags: java, shell, unix, cron

I have written a shell script which has a Demo class having main method.

Now when I am running my shell using `./file.sh` .It works fine.

But now I have configured a cronjob to execute that file every 5 mins using `crontab`.

But this is giving me a `classnotfoundException`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/Demo
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.Demo
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Met
```

Here is my shell file.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo 'Starts'
lib1='HitURL.jar'

CLASSPATH=$lib1
java -cp HitURL.jar:. com.example.Demo http://www.google.com
echo 'Ends'
```

How i can remove this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your HitURL.jar file located?

Comment: In the same folder as shell script. /home/mine/script

Comment: `at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Met` <--what's the rest of this? My guess is the script running doesn't have the right permissions.The fact the AccessController is throwing hints at it.

Comment: @DanielChapman: No, that's just part of the JVM's process for starting a program. Go to a command line and type `java no.such.Class`, and you'll get the same stacktrace.

Answer (score 4):

I would bet good money that the problem is to do with the fact that when you run that script by hand you run it from the directory where `HitURL.jar` is -- whereas when cron runs the process, it would probably use the root directory as the current directory.
As such I'd change it to include the full path to `HitURL.jar` in the `lib1` variable -- then make sure you also reference it in the `-cp` parameter something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo 'Starts'
lib1='/full/path/to/HitURL.jar'

CLASSPATH=$lib1
java -cp $lib1:. com.example.Demo http://www.google.com
```

Comment: Just seen your answer above regarding the path /home/mine/script -- so lib1 should be something like this: lib1='/home/mine/script/HitURL.jar'

Comment: Also, I would recommend have lib1 to contain the dot too: `lib1=/home/mine/script/HitURL.jar:.`

Comment: you can add all the jar's you need in `lib1` and separate them by :

Comment: I have one more jar other than Hiturl.jar .How i can put both jar in classpath ? Comma separted?

Comment: No, colon separated: `lib1='/home/mine/scripts/HitURL.jar:/another/path/to/a.jar'`

Comment: If lib1, lib2 and lib3 each contains a full path to a jar file then yes, that is correct. Though I would recommend you place everything into a single variable -- makes it easier to read the code and track where everything is; otherwise every time you look at that code you have to track down where lib1, lib2 and lib3 is declared and what are their values rather than just locate one single variable declaration.

Comment: But after this change, it has convert all `/` to . Error showing is                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: http:..www.google.com

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean :O Can you be more explicit?